# Is it possible to add button inside Input control?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create my own customised timepicker that works on IE as well as chrome.
Time format is to be 'hh:mm'.
So i created like

```
<input ng-model="timeHours" type="number" class="hours" placeholder="00" min="0" max="23" step="1">
<span class="lap-time-sep">:</span>
<input ng-model="timeMinutes" type="number" class="minutes" placeholder="00" min="0" max="45" step="15">
```

Now I want to show the 'up- down' spinner always and also in IE.
Is there any way I can add my own buttons inside input control?

Comment: It is not possible to add button inside input control but you can keep it aside and apply css to those buttons so that it will look like one component

Comment: Thanks When I am trying to put buttons in it I want it in line on right but its just overlapping.  <input ng-model="timeHours" type="number" class="hours form-control" placeholder="00" min="0" max="23" step="1">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <button class="dashboard-time-up"><i class="fa fa-sort-up up-img"></i></button>
            <button class="dashboard-time-down"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></button>
        </div>

Comment: CSS:  .dashboard-time-up {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-left: -10px;
    }

    .dashboard-time-down {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-left: -12px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .up-img {
        height: 10px;
        margin: 0px;
        align-self: stretch;
    }

    .hours {
        width: 40px;
        padding: 3px 0 0 3px;
        float: left;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add your own button inside `input`

You might(I am not sure about this one) be able to do that by changing CSS, but that too is not a general solution as different browsers use different CSS properties to set their `input type=number` spinners and there is no surety that it would work on all browsers

See **[here](https://css-tricks.com/numeric-inputs-a-comparison-of-browser-defaults/)**

As a work around,you can achieve this using [Spinners](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/)

Set it on DOM ready

```
angular.module("MyApp", [])
  .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $('#hour').spinner({
        min: 0,
        max: 23,
        step: 1,
        spin: function(event, ui) {
            $scope.hh = ui.value;
          $scope.$apply();
            }
   });
   $('#minutes').spinner({
        min: 0,
        max: 45,
        step: 15,
        spin: function(event, ui) {
            $scope.mm = ui.value;
          $scope.$apply();
            }
   });
    });
  });
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/5cjpybvw/3/)**

You can change the CSS as per your needs